# Get amount of likes Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I always used this URL(https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE-ID]) via JavaScript to get the amount of likes, but now I get an **error:**

> "An access token is required to request this resource."

- Is there another possibility to get the likes without an token?
- Can I set my access token directly into the request (security)? Is the token a secret token?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to get it without a token. I can use the following URL:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20fan_count%20from%20page%20where%20page_id=[PAGEID]&format=json

Answer (score 0):

- No, you have to use a Token. But you can use an App Access Token that does not require authorization.
- You should always keep any Token secret, only use it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get it without token. Read more about how to generate tokens [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)